# SPF Record Gmail sets on SPAM folder

Tags: dns, gmail, spf

I'm working on this for about 5 hours and I still couldn't find a way to not send the emails of my private server to the spam folder of gmail.

The error I'm receiving in google is:

```
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 212.113.177.3 is neither permitted nor denied by domain of info@skiuwi.com) client-ip=212.113.177.3;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 212.113.177.3 is neither permitted nor denied by domain of info@skiuwi.com) smtp.mail=info@skiuwi.com
```

I actually do not know what d'hell is the IP 212.113.177.3, but a search around the google told me to add some SPF to my domain, so I did.

[image]

But the emails continue to go to the SPAM folder. So I went to the [SPF Record Checker](http://spf.myisp.ch/)
and they output the following results:

[image]

What am I doing wrong in the SPF?

Comment: Hard to say, given that you've masked the domain name. Also note that these emails may still go to spam even with valid SPF records.

Comment: Give me two minutes, I will put the two images without the domain name masked.

Comment: @ceejayoz see it now.

Comment: As ceejayoz mentioned in his answer below, there are many variables that go into how receiving servers decide to place mail in spam. You can also check Spam Assassin against your messages to get a look at what their results tell you. Here's a good API to check: http://spamcheck.postmarkapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine your two SPF records into one.

```
v=spf1 ip4:212.113.177.3 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

Note that adding SPF isn't a magic bullet. Many components go into spam filtering - content analysis, the reputation of the sending IP, the age of the domain name being used, blacklisting, DKIM, etc.

Comment: Your answer is right. Plus, I had to change the configuration of "SMTP Relayer" in my hMailServer to none, since that was making my emails going to the SPAM folder.  After changing that I started to receive th e emails on Gmail normally. Although the problem still persists for example in Hotmail and the reason of that is the blacklist I believe. I had my IP in three blacklists..I manage to remove from two, but the other one is more difficult and I will try to figure out with SpamRats what's the cause. 

Thank you.